# Selecting first nth rows by groups using AWK

Tags: awk

I have the following file with 4 fields. There are 3 groups in field 2, and the 4th field consists 0's and 1's.

The first field is just the index.

I like to use AWK to do the following task

1. Select the first 3 rows of group 1 (Note that group 1 has only 2 rows). The number of rows is based on the number of 1's found in the 4th field times 3.
2. Select the first 6 rows of group 2. The number of rows is  based on the number of 1's found in the 4th field times 3.
3. Select the first 9 rows of group 3. The number of rows is  based on the number of 1's found in the 4th field times 3.

So 17 rows are selected for the output file.

Thank you for your help.

```
Input 

1   1  TN1148 1
2   1  S52689 0
3   2  TA2081 1
4   2  TA2592 1
5   2  TA4011 0
6   2  TA4246 0
7   2  TA4275 0
8   2  TB0159 0
9   2  TB0392 0
10  3  TB0454 1
11  3  TB0496 1
12  3  TB1181 1
13  3  TC0027 0
14  3  TC1340 0
15  3  TC2247 0
16  3  TC3094 0
17  3  TD0106 0
18  3  TD1146 0
19  3  TD1796 0
20  3  TD3587 0

Output 

 1  1  TN1148 1
 2  1  S52689 0
 3  2  TA2081 1
 4  2  TA2592 1
 5  2  TA4011 0
 6  2  TA4246 0
 7  2  TA4275 0
 8  2  TB0159 0
 10 3  TB0454 1
 11 3  TB0496 1
 12 3  TB1181 1
 13 3  TC0027 0
 14 3  TC1340 0
 15 3  TC2247 0
 16 3  TC3094 0
 17 3  TD0106 0
 18 3  TD1146 0
```

Comment: You need to reformulate the question because it's not very clear to me what you are calling groups and what you are calling fields. In awk, fields have a very specific meaning which is further confusing the problem as stated.

Comment: I edited your question so that the Input/Output format is readable now. For future notice, highlight your code and hit CTRL+K or hit the '101' icon in the editor.

Comment: Field 2 has 3 "groups" 1, 2 and 3. Hope this clarifies. Thanks SiegeX.

Comment: you might want to accept an answer to each of your questions.

Answer (score 2):

The key to this awk program is to pass the input file in twice:  Once to count how many rows you want and once to print them.

```
awk '
    NR == FNR {wanted_rows[$2] += 3*$4; next} 
    --wanted_rows[$2] >= 0 {print}
' input_file.txt input_file.txt
```

Comment: Dear Glenn- Wow, I just test your programme , it works fine. I have a much larger file to test about 1.8M rows and will keep you posted. - Thank you so much - BTW, This is the first time I find  the same input file is passed twice. Never thought about this idea

Comment: Both answers are valid. They both exhibit their elegance in their own right.

Answer (score 0):

```
#!/usr/bin/awk -f
# by Dennis Williamson - 2010-12-02
# for http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4334167/selecting-first-nth-rows-by-groups-using-awk
$2 == prev {
    count += $4
    groupcount++
    array[idx++] = $0
}
$2 != prev {
    if (NR > 1) {
        for (i=0; i<count*3; i++) {
            if (i == groupcount) break
            print array[i]
        }
    }
    prev = $2
    count = 1
    groupcount = 1
    split("", array) # delete the array
    idx = 0
    array[idx++] = $0
}
END {
    for (i=0; i<count*3; i++) {
        if (i == groupcount) break
        print array[i]
    }
}
```

Comment: Dear Dennis- Many thanks for your effort. I just tested the programme, but it did not produce the expected output. The output has 37 lines and the rows are out of order. Any possible modification? Cheers. Tony

Comment: @Tony: Using the sample data you provided, its output is exactly the same as your sample output. Do you get the correct results from the sample data? Can you be more specific about how it's not working?

Comment: Dennis- First, I got 37 rows and the first few lines, I obtained are1   1  TN1148 1
2   1  S52689 0
3   2  TA2081 1
1   1  TN1148 1
2   1  S52689 0
...

Comment: Dennis- First, I got 37 rows and the first few rows are shown below: 1   1  TN1148 1
2   1  S52689 0
3   2  TA2081 1
1   1  TN1148 1
2   1  S52689 0... 16  3  TC3094 0
17  3  TD0106 0
18  3  TD1146 0
I do not know where I did wrong. I saved the programme as select.script and then to run it awk -f select.script input.txt > out.txt - Your help is much appreciated.

Comment: @Tony: So it repeats the first couple of rows? What version of AWK? I'm using `gawk` 3.1.6, but it runs correctly for me even with the `--traditional` or `--posix` switches. Be sure you didn't get an extra `print` statement in there somehow.

Comment: It runs fine now. The errors occurs when I copied the programme and pasted to Vi editor. Some lines were missing at the beginning.- Many thanks again. Your guys have been wonderful- Tony